# Why am I getting this weird clipping/incorrect vertices on my model?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I checked the model for extra vertices but it appears there are none. For some reason when I try to add the solidify modifier (to add a character outline) it gets all funny and makes it like this. It pretends like the vertices on the cheek line are absolutely set in stone, since I had the same issue when trying to do a subdivision surface modifier. It treated it as a hard line and made the subdivision look funny.

[image: The head model with issues .png]

Comment: Solidify modifier extends the faces in the direction of their normal. If two adjacent faces have inverted normals, this can cause artifacts. In edit mode select everything then mesh >  Recalculate (SHIFT N)

Comment: @Gorgious Thank you, this worked for the most part for fixing the weird artifacts.